# Rack::Request.send :include What is Alex doing in Ruby Geocoder

Tags: ruby

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

I love the Ruby Geocoder Gem for all of it's amazing meta-programming, most of which I simply don't understand.

Does anyone know what is going on in the bottom of the Geocoder::Request Module?

There is a simple 3 line block that mystifies me:

It's actually OUTSIDE of the Module definition and it reads as

```
    if defined?(Rack) and defined?(Rack::Request)
      Rack::Request.send :include, Geocoder::Request
    end
```

There is no predefine method .include on Rack::Request  so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

That blocks means that if the condition is met, the `Geocoder::Request` module is going to be included in the `Rack::Request` class, so in essence is extending the `Rack::Request` functionality to include the `location` method just defined. The `include` method lives in the ruby [Module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-include).

This is the file you're refering to: [Geocoder Request](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/request.rb)